# select git branch on ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh for my main terminal on linuxmint 21, when I run command gb or git branch, I got this result:

```
  boba
* main
(END)
```

I use zsh from this tutorial: [FROM HERE](https://techviewleo.com/install-and-use-zsh-with-oh-my-zsh-on-linux-mint/)

And this is the cheat sheet: [CHEATSHEET COMMAND](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Oh-My-Zsh_Git.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

Can I choose the boba branch in this situation?

Comment: This is not related to zsh, just a thing about git usages... You can use `git checkout boba` to switch to branch `boba`.

Comment: i ask in different case, the zsh show that result with (*) is that mean something? i thing it means i can change the branch from there, am i wrong? or it just showing the branch?

Comment: The result is just a message with a pager. **oh-my-zsh** sets `PAGER=less` and `LESS=-R` so the output of `git branch` is displayed individually. The star only indicates the current branch, and you cannot switch branches with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Completely different answer after clarification of problem.

That's because the command you ran lists the available branches using a *pager*.

The one marked with '*' is the current branch, and the "(END)" is how a pager tells you that the previous was the last line.

You cannot use the pager to switch branches. To switch you use

```
git checkout boba
```

With all the bells and whistles oh-my-zsh incorporates, you may bring up a selection widget by typing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after the checkout arg:

```
git checkout <TAB>
```

(I don't use oh-my-zsh so it may not work).

Comment: AFAIK, the dash mentioned on that website is not a shell, but a GUI application on macOS making it easier for users to check API docs.

Comment: @SimonSmith That's true. But Coldalpha mentions he is using zsh on Linux and to get the same "abbreviations" he would use aliases as shown. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: The tutorial suggests using **oh-my-zsh** and adding git to the plugins list in `~/.zshrc`. After doing these things, the aliases are created by the git plugin, and there's no need to create them by ourselves. Since OP was following the tutorial, I don't think that's what he meant to ask.

Comment: im sorry sir, i mean , when i run 'git branch', my terminal got blank and i get  thats result (at the top), so i just can quit with turn q button on my keyboard, so can i select the branch or something? or it just show the branch and we can't do nothing with them?

Comment: @Coldalpha Ok, that's because that command lists the available branches. The one marked with '*' is the current branch, and the "(END)" is how a pager tells you that the previous was the last line. You cannot use the pager to switch branches. To switch you use `git checkout boba`.